# How to Customize HTMLReports of Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm trying to customize HTMLReport of gatling to get results (and charts) between 2 specific time (I don't want all results only a time range.

How can I do that ? I didn't found a documentation about that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's officially not possible to customize the report with regular version of Gatling.

To get another report there is no option but to get Gatling Frontline : https://gatling.io/gatling-frontline/